# How i can covert column to rows when column name is repeat via number in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe column name like this

```
id salary year emp_type salary1 year1 emp_type1 salary2 year2 emp_type2 .. salary9 year9 emp_type9
1   xx    xx   xx .. ..
2   ..    ..
3
```

i wan to pivot column  to row like this

```
id           salary            year                emp_type
-------------------------------------------------------------------
       value of salary     value of year     value of emp_type
       value of salary1    value of year1    value of emp_type1
             ..                  ..                .. 
             ..                  ..                ..
       value of salary9    value of year9    value of emp_type9
```

Answer (score 0):

If columns are guaranteed to be in this order, you can simply create a new dataframe from the reshaped old one:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(old_df.values.reshape((-1, 3)), 
                      columns=['salary', 'year', 'emp_type'])
```

The new dataframe will not keep the old index, though.

Comment: thank you for answer. but i don't understand -1 and 3

Comment: @devnext shape is (rows, columns, *whatever_other_dimensions). Replacing any dimension with -1 means to force other dimensions and calculate the size of this one afterwards. Here, reshape(-1, 3) means: reshape to three columns, whatever number of rows it takes

Comment: thank you for answer . but not working it shown this error  "cannot reshape array of size 176293 into shape (3)"

Comment: @devnext There is one extra column. Is id a column in the original dataframe or an index?

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by @Marat should work. Here I used 9 columns and it works.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['1000', 2011, 'Type1', '2000', 2012, 'Type2', '3000', 2013, 'Type3',
                   '4000', 2014, 'Type4', '5000', 2015, 'Type5', '6000', 2016, 'Type6',
                   '8000', 2018, 'Type7', '8000', 2018, 'Type8', '9000', 2019, 'Type9'])
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,3),columns=['salary', 'year', 'emp_type'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  salary  year emp_type
0   1000  2011    Type1
1   2000  2012    Type2
2   3000  2013    Type3
3   4000  2014    Type4
4   5000  2015    Type5
5   6000  2016    Type6
6   8000  2018    Type7
7   8000  2018    Type8
8   9000  2019    Type9
```